# Features and Story graph || input to keras policy

Tags: python-3.x, keras, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

Could you please let me know **how are you identifying the features** you're passing to keras policy.
I could see story graphs are being created during agent.load_data.

Could you please share live example so that I can tune the parameters and hyperparameters to get the best out of keras lstm model.

Rasa Core version: 0.11.12

Python version: 3.5

Operating system (windows, osx, ...):windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selected feature depends on the used policy and its configuration.
You can specify your configuration in a [policy configuration file](https://rasa.com/docs/core/policies/). If you use the "embedding policy", you can also define the layers etc. of the used LSTM in this configuration file.

The features are identified from

- intents so far
- last actions
- current slot values / entities values

Have a look at the [documentation on featurization](https://rasa.com/docs/core/api/featurizer/#) for more details since this highly depends on the used policy configuration (you can select different featurizers).

With rasa_core version 0.12 you can only [compare the accuracy of different policies](https://rasa.com/docs/core/evaluation/#comparing-policies) with the command `python -m rasa_core.train compare`. This is probably helpful if you want to finetune that.